# Iterate through web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, loops, asp.net-web-api

I have web.config section arranged as follows:

```
<Section>
  <service1>
    <add name="Web" info="xyz"/>     
  </service1>
  <service2>
    <add name="App" info="xyz"/>     
  </service2>
  <service3>
    <add name="Data" info="xyz"/>     
  </service3>  
</Section>
```

I have iterated through every element by using:

```
var mySection = (Sections)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Section");
```

and

```
foreach (SectionsElement element in mySection.service1)
foreach (SectionsElement element in mySection.service2)
foreach (SectionsElement element in mySection.service3)
```

However this requires a lot of copied code in each foreach as they perform more or less the same thing.
Any ideas how I could generalize this iteration?

---

**Edit:** Managed to solve this by creating a list of objects.

```
var allservices = new List<object>(){
  mySection.service1,
  mySection.service2,
  mySection.service3
}
```

And then iterating:

```
foreach (IEnumerable service in allservices)
  {
    foreach (SectionsElement element in service)
    {
      //repetitive code
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use interfaces. If `mySection.service1`, `.service2` and `.service3` implement the same interface, say `IMyService`, you can easily do something like this:

```
var services = new IMyService[] 
{ 
    mySection.service1, 
    mySection.service2, 
    mySection.service3 
};

foreach (var service in services)
{
    foreach (SectionsElement element in service)
    {
        // repetitive code
    }
}
```

Comment: Should service1/2/3 implement the interface by adding the elements to a List or array?

Comment: @AntonJ no, theirclass should implement it.

Comment: Thanks! Managed to solve in a slightly different way but spurred on by your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a collection of Configs :

```
[ConfigurationProperty("Service", IsRequired = true)]
public string Service
 {
 ...
 }



public class ServiceConfigCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    public ServiceConfig this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return base.BaseGet(index) as ServiceConfig;
        }
        set
        {
            if (base.BaseGet(index) != null)
            {
                base.BaseRemoveAt(index);
            }
            this.BaseAdd(index, value);
        }
    }


    protected override System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new ServiceConfig();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((ServiceConfig)element).Service;
    }
}

public class ServiceConfigSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Entries", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ServiceConfigCollection),
        AddItemName = "add",
        ClearItemsName = "clear",
        RemoveItemName = "remove")]
    public ServiceConfigCollection Entries
    {
        get
        {
            return (ServiceConfigCollection)base["Entries"];
        }
    }
}
```

which in the config files gives:

```
<configSections>
  <section
    name="Services"
    type="xxx.classes.ServiceConfigSection, xxx"
    allowLocation="true"
    allowDefinition="Everywhere"
  />
</configSections>

<Services>
  <Entries>
    <add .../>
    <add .../>
  </Entries>
</Services>
```

Then in the code :

```
var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Services") as ServiceConfigSection;
/* do something with section.Entries */
```